# Transpose a DataFrame based on the amount of Columns with Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to transpose the columns with values and not NaN in columns numbered 1-11. With each column transpose I need to copy the "Operator id" and the rest of the data to each new row. It is possible for each "Operator id" there can be up to 11 entries or only 1.

I have tried df.T and df.stack().

```
df.head()
Out[7]: 
    Operator id  CountryID                  1                   2        3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
0    john.smith      376.0     jake.sha.human                 NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    john.wayne      826.0  sambaser@fake.com                 NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    mike.evans      840.0    ardenn@fake.com  isabellac@fake.com  sam.cha  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  sarah.wagner      356.0    nathan@fake.com                 NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4    two.chains      784.0        AR@fake.com         hr@fake.com      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

```
    Operator id  CountryID               TransCol
0    john.smith      376.0          jake.sha.human
1    john.wayne      826.0          sambaser@fake.com
2    mike.evans      840.0          ardenn@fake.com
3    mike.evans      840.0          isabellac@fake.com
4    mike.evans      840.0          sam.cha
5    sarah.wagner    356.0          nathan@fake.com
6    two.chains      784.0          AR@fake.com
7    two.chains      784.0          hr@fake.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `melt`:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Operator id', 'CountryID']).drop('variable', 1).dropna()
```

Output:

```
     Operator id  CountryID               value
0     john.smith      376.0      jake.sha.human
1     john.wayne      826.0   sambaser@fake.com
2     mike.evans      840.0     ardenn@fake.com
3   sarah.wagner      356.0     nathan@fake.com
4     two.chains      784.0         AR@fake.com
7     mike.evans      840.0  isabellac@fake.com
9     two.chains      784.0         hr@fake.com
12    mike.evans      840.0             sam.cha
```

Or `stack`:

```
(df.set_index(['Operator id', 'CountryID'])
   .stack()
   .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index(name='TransCol')
)
```

Output:

```
    Operator id  CountryID            TransCol
0    john.smith      376.0      jake.sha.human
1    john.wayne      826.0   sambaser@fake.com
2    mike.evans      840.0     ardenn@fake.com
3    mike.evans      840.0  isabellac@fake.com
4    mike.evans      840.0             sam.cha
5  sarah.wagner      356.0     nathan@fake.com
6    two.chains      784.0         AR@fake.com
7    two.chains      784.0         hr@fake.com
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for something "melt" accomplishes for some time now. How would I keep the entries with a NaN in Column 1? I've tried altering the dropna clause.

Comment: `fillna` column `1` with something unique, and replace that by `NaN` afterwards?

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a slicker way to do this with stack() but you can do something very simple like:

```py
id_cols = ['Operator id', 'CountryID']
final_df = df[id_cols].drop_duplicates()
for col in [c for c in df.columns if c not in id_cols]:
    col_df = df[id_cols + [col].dropna().rename(columns={col: 'TransCol'})
    final_df = final_df.append(col_df, sort=False)
```